# Simple questions on javasript: socket.io and arrow function method () => {}

Tags: javascript, socket.io, arrow-functions, emit

I'm currently studying basic javascript features, and I am quite struggling with the arrow function method. So I from what I've learnt, if there is only one parameter, it doesn't matter if we use parenthesis or not like the code below:

```
(singleParam) => { statements }
singleParam => { statements }
```

Then when emitting events in socket IO, to simplify the codes

```
// server-side
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.emit("hello", "world");
});

// client-side
socket.on("hello", (arg) => {
  console.log(arg); // world
});
```

could be simplified as

```
// server-side
io.on("connection", socket => {
  socket.emit("hello", "world");
});

// client-side
socket.on("hello", arg => {
  console.log(arg); // world
});
```

This is working fine in my project, thus I wonder the necessity of using parenthesis when using arrow method function. Maybe I'm not fully grasping the concepts, can anyone explain this method a little bit easier way? Thanks.

Comment: You can put multiple paramters inside the parenthesis. For 1 parameter either way is fine.

Comment: Read the documentation on arrow functions. Learn about it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 0):

If using exactly one parameter in an arrow function you don't need to use the parenthesis. Some developers prefer to always add them however for consistency and readability.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions